# What is the difference between snap and full synchronization?

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization, full-node

I would like to know about the differences between snap sync and full sync in as simple words as possible. For example, what commands cannot be executed when using snap sync versus full sync, or something like that.

Comment: snap downloads the state in a single download, the full sync downloads the state in batches of `state object`s , the difference is that snap is faster, that's the only difference

Comment: not 100% sure, but you should check that with either `eth_getBalance` or `eth_getStorageAt` for specific blocks?